# Send message to original App Domain

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, appdomain

I have an application that creates a new app domain like this:

```
private static AppDomain domain = null;

private static void LoadAndLaunchAppDomain(string assemblyFile, string typeName)
{
    AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup()
    {
        ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        ShadowCopyFiles = "true"
    };

    domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ClientKernel", null, setup);
    domain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(domain_UnhandledException);
    ClientKernelLauncher launcher = (ClientKernelLauncher)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyFile, typeName);
    launcher.Launch();
}

static void domain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // handler
}
```

At some point an exception is thrown and the flow reaches inside the HANDLER. What I actually want is to recreate the domain when this happens. What I noticed is that the handler is actually running on the "ClientKernel" app domain and not the original domain that created it.

How can communicate back to the original domain and tell it to call again the `LoadAndLaunchAppDomain()` method?

Comment: If you remove `static` from both methods, does your code still work?  If so, does it then execute in the correct `AppDomain` (since the original object was created in the original `AppDomain`)?  Note that if instance methods are allowed for the callbacks, you may still need to make your object `Serializable`/`MarshalByRefObject` for this to work.

Comment: I can't remove it. I am working with a static class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`AppDomain.DoCallBack()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback.aspx) to call a method on another `AppDomain`.

I am not sure if that will work once an unhandled exception is thrown in calling `AppDomain`. But, you could give it a shot.

Comment: Ok but how do I get a reference to the main(original) app domain inside the exception handler?

Comment: I found a way to get the reference. This was not the exact/complete solution but I still used it and it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
AppDomain hostDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ClientKernel", null, setup);
domain.UnhandledException += (s, e) => {
   hostDomain.DoCallBack(() => { SomeStaticClass.LoadAndLaunchAppDomain("someAssembly", "someClassName"); }
}
```

I don't know what the name of your class hosting the code is so you'll need to change SomeStaticClass to the right class name.

Comment: Inside the handler I don't have access to the someAssembly and someClassName parameters, and they are initially given as params from outside the static class. Actually I do have scope but they are set to null as the handler is running in the new domain.